# Why async code is run on worker thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I am playing with the async/await in the C# and while I think that I understand most of the concepts, I can not explain why the code line "var rxres = await ..." first time runs on my UDP thread, and after further receptions of the packets runs on the worker thread. As far as I understand, I am not "yielding" back to the thread function and it is still alive and so all invocations of ReceiveAsync should run on the thread I created.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ewh = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);

        var udpThread = new Thread(async () =>
        {
            ListenUdpAsync().Wait();
        });
        udpThread.Name = "UDP THREAD";
        udpThread.Start();

        ewh.WaitOne();
    }
    static public async Task ListenUdpAsync()
    {
        var localPort = 5555;
        var localBind = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, localPort);

        using (var udpc = new UdpClient(localBind))
        {
            while(true)
            {
                var rxres = await udpc.ReceiveAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Rx From: " + rxres.RemoteEndPoint);
                Console.WriteLine("Rx Data: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rxres.Buffer));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am not "yielding" back to the thread function

The method yields once hitting `await udpc.ReceiveAsync()`, that is how async-await works. `ListenAsync` itself synchronously blocks, but since there is no sync context that comes into play, the continuation is able to marshal itself onto an arbitrary thread pool thread.

> so all invocations of ReceiveAsync should run on the thread I created.

Not really. Generally, when you're running inside a console application, it uses the default `TaskScheduler`, which internally uses the thread pool to execute continuations on an arbitrary threadpool thread. Ones `ReceiveAsync()` completes, its continuation needs to be scheduled somewhere, and that place is on the thread pool.

On a side note - there is no reason to use the `async` modifier on the delegate, as you're not awaiting anything inside, but synchronously blocking.

Comment: Re: side node - Yes, I am aware of that. It is just a relic from trying "await ListenUdpAsync();" instead of "ListenUdpAsync().Wait();"